# How to include chart or table

Tags: support

Screenshots within questions or answers are disfavored because their content isn't indexed. That makes good sense.

In my answer to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/173625/how-long-before-departure-do-i-need-to-get-to-lille-europe-for-a-eurostar-to-bru), I nevertheless included screenshots of two charts, as the charts' size and content made using the quotation mark composition tool unworkable. When I returned to the question the next day, I found that the answer had been amended to successfully include the charts' information in an apparently searchable fashion. This was clearly an improvement to my answer.

I didn't know that was possible. How does one do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The voluminous instructions are to be found in MSE and are impossible to summarise briefly.

[New Feature: Table Support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support)

Comment: Thanks. That's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> How to include chart or table?

It's not possible to include a chart aside from inserting an image, with the exception of simple tables (grids).